# Use of INDIRECT in data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, syntax

I want to apply Excel's INDIRECT function in data validation in VBA.

I am using VBA to populate the data validation criteria, and using INDIRECT to find the appropriate workbook named range from another named range via HLOOKUP.

I think my issue is with the syntax of the VBA code. I can't work out what the correct placement of the double quotation marks. This returns an error 400 notification.

I have the following (functioning code sections omitted for clarity). Column F referenced by HLOOKUP contains a user-selectable value, and DepartmentRef is a named range:

```
Sub AddNewRoom()
Dim targetRow As Integer
targetRow = Range("EndRoomData").Row
With Worksheets("RoomData")
    With .Range("G" & targetRow).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(hlookup(F" & targetRow & ",DepartmentRef,2,false))"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

When I change the validation formula to remove the code variable, the code functions correctly:

```
With .Range("G" & targetRow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(hlookup(F7,DepartmentRef,2,false))"
End With
```

Comment: I have just tried `Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("k2").Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(vlookup(1,test!A:B,2,0))"` and it worked fine.  Can you give a bit more insight?  Is `targetRow` populated if you place a break point, just before the validation setting?   Also, i dont see how you can get a list from that?  Is it not best to set the value off this, then a static formula could be used or added?

Comment: Also, does the formula produced return a value, so if the derrived range is say "Q1000000" by error, this will cause the formula to produce an error?

Comment: There will be issues if the formula returns an error, but I would not think that should depend on how `Fn` is constructed.  Your syntax appears correct.  Also, you will not be able to address an row > 32767, since that is the limit of the `Integer` data type.  What is the content of `TargetRow` when you are creating the formula?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: yes, 'targetRow' is populated at run time, it is being used in many other parts of the code without problem.  The issue appears to be in the data validation setting, as if an invalid reference is being created.  The code aborts with an error box with the message "400" only; no option to End/Debug as would normally be expected. No data validation settings appear in the target cell.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: 'targetRow' starts at row 6, and is unlikely to extend beyond row 1000, so the integer limit is unlikely to be an issue in practice, and certainly not in testing, but I note the potential limitation.  In my testing, it has been limited to <20 so far.

Comment: @RichardJelbert With no `End/Debug` option, that suggests either that the code is not in a Regular module, or that your error trapping errors are not set to `break on unhandled errors`.  Is either of those the case?

Comment: With the addition of an error display subroutine, the error 400 is further described as follows: "Can't push objects off the sheet".

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I created the code in a Sheet, rather than Module.  I have transferred to a Module, and now receive the error message at the line '.Add Type' ... : Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Most likely, at run time, when `"=indirect(hlookup(F" & targetRow & ",DepartmentRef,2,false))"` is evaluated, the result is not valid.  Try seeing the results of a `debug.print "=indirect(hlookup(F" & targetRow & ",DepartmentRef,2,false))"` line inserted just before your `With Worksheets("RoomData")` line

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the output text line is '=indirect(hlookup(F8,DepartmentRef,2,false))' as I would expect (or whatever row number is selected by 'targetRow').

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I will either get, or not get, an error running the macro, depending on whether the contents of `Fn` match an entry in the first row of `DepartmentRef`.  It makes no difference if I use `"F" & targetRow`, or if I hard code something like `F1`.  If the macro is in a worksheet, I will get the `400` error.  If it is in a regular module, it will return a `1004` error, but they both mean the same thing. `Application-defined or object-defined error`.  I don't see the same message you do.  There is something different in your environment that I am not seeing.

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening now.  At the time that I am attempting to run the code, the referenced cell in column F is empty, and therefore an error is returned by the data validation (not sure how I missed this previously).  When I apply manually, Excel gives me the option to ignore the error and continue, but the macro recorder gives no output for this process and I cannot (so far) find any way to code for this step.  So to work around it, I temporarily enter a legitimate value in column F, then delete it after applying validation in column G.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use direct 'name' cell reference but try:

```
Formula1:="=INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(" & Worksheets("RoomData").Cells(targetRow, 6).Address(False, False) & ",DepartmentRef,2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: thanks, I can see why that might be better, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I had the same error, but was gone with above solution. Do you work with an US language-version? and with a , as formula delimiter or ; ?

Comment: Windows system language is English (Australia); selected Excel proofing languages are English (Australia) and English (US).  I assume you mean delimiter between arguments in formulae, etc: I use ','.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the validation formula must return a result at the time the code runs.  If the cell referenced by HLOOKUP is empty, then Excel sees a Source error and the code terminates.  If this error occurs when entering the reference manually, Excel allows you to continue regardless, but you cannot (so far as I can tell) do this in VBA.  To get around this, enter a (legitimate) value in the referenced cell prior to entering the validation details, then delete the reference value afterwards. For example:

```
With Worksheets("RoomData")    
    .Range("F" & targetRow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Names("DepartmentName").RefersToRange(1, 1)
    strFormula = "=INDIRECT(HLOOKUP(" &    
        Worksheets("RoomData").Cells(targetRow,6).Address(True, True) & ",DepartmentRef,2,FALSE))"
    With .Range("G" & targetRow).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strFormula
    End With
    .Range("F" & targetRow).ClearContents
End With
```